# PyTorch: How to append tensors into a list using loops

Tags: python, list, pytorch, tensor

I have the following code which outputs 2 arrays in a list:

```
arr1 = np.array([[1.,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])

arr_split = np.array_split(arr1,
                           indices_or_sections = 2,
                           axis = 0)

arr_split
```

Output:

```
[array([[1., 2., 3.],
        [4., 5., 6.]]), array([[7., 8., 9.]])]
```

How do I cast these 2 arrays into PyTorch tensors and put them into a list using `for` (or `while`) loops, so that they look like this:

```
[tensor([[1., 2., 3.],
         [4., 5., 6.]], dtype=torch.float64),
tensor([[7., 8., 9.]], dtype=torch.float64)]
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure I follow... do you just want `[torch.from_numpy(a) for a in arr_split]`? https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.from_numpy.html + https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: Thanks, this works and it's what I am after! Didn't thought about using list comprehensions...

Answer (score 0):

Better you convert it to tensor at first place and then you can use [`torch.Tensor.split`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.split)

```py
arr1 = np.array([[1.,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
t_arr1 = torch.from_numpy(arr1)

t_arr1.split(split_size=2)
(tensor([[1., 2., 3.],
        [4., 5., 6.]], dtype=torch.float64), 
 tensor([[7., 8., 9.]], dtype=torch.float64))
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn’t quite work for me because I need the steps to be in the same order as what I had mentioned in my question above.